# Web application design - responsive layout vs. more separated layouts

Tags: css, web

I am now working on something bigger than simple web page. It should be accessible on mobile/tablet/pc. Is better to use framework like http://foundation.zurb.com/ or implement more layouts for different end devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you choose a framework or not, you will still have to write some custom CSS for different view ports.

But I would go with a framework regardless. They do all the heavy lifting for you, and hundreds of people have worked on them, which makes them more robust than anything you can come up with in a short period of time.

All you have to do is write some additional `@media` queries to customise your styles for different view ports.

Comment: Good answer. Some clarity for the OP: Target viewport size ranges rather than specific devices. There are many devices (new ones every day) and specifically targeting them all is a nightmare.